# MALFORMED Query, unexpected token

Tags: visualforce, soql, javascript, api

I have a simple query in my JavaScript within a VisualForce page. and it is giving me MALFormed Query exception, unexpected token: annualVolume. Here is the code:

```
function queryPricingModel()
{
    try
    {
        var myQuery = sforce.connection.query("SELECT BP__c FROM PC_BP_Matrix__c WHERE StartVolume__c < annualVolume");
        pcBP = myQuery;
    }
    catch(error)
    {
        alert(error.faultstring);
    }
}
```

Please Help, thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Where do you assign value to **annualVolume** variable? If it's a JS variable in the global scope, you cannot simply pass a JS varible to the query by placing it in the query string. What you should do is create a query string with value of the annualVolume variable.

E.g.

```
function queryPricingModel()
{
    try
    {
        var myQuery = "SELECT BP__c FROM PC_BP_Matrix__c WHERE StartVolume__c < " + annualVolume;
        pcBP = sforce.connection.query(myQuery);
    }
    catch(error)
    {
        alert(error.faultstring);
    }
}
```

As a proof of concept, you can try to replace **annualVolume** variable with a literal value in your initial example.

Comment: annualVolume is a global variable which will be assigned a value when the user enters the number on the page.

Comment: As I assumed. In that case, try the example I've given you. You cannot place a JS variable in a string literal (between quotation marks) and expect it to resolve properly. What you have done is simply written a string containing "annualVolume" characters.

Comment: I see what you are saying now. I was pass the word "annualVolume" in the query string instead of its value. thank you so much.

Comment: No problem, glad I could help ;)